# How can I configure werker to handle postgis with django

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, postgis, wercker

I've just setup wercker for python3.4, it seems good - but I am not sure how I should get it to install/configure postgis and django.

There is some information related: http://blog.wercker.com/2013/11/18/django-16.html and https://github.com/wercker/wercker-django-example/blob/master/wercker.yml - but it seems rather outdated.

Answer (score 0):

The docs you refer to are of the "old" wercker. They've  transitioned to a Docker based build system now, which is the recommended way to go.
The new (docker based) documentation [can be found here](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/about/index.html).

So basically all you need to do is build using a docker image that already contains Django and Postgis. [This one might work](https://hub.docker.com/r/83tb/docker-django-postgis/~/dockerfile/).